# RS 232 issue in ATEasy

Tags: serial-port, ateasy

I am using `ATEasy` 7 142g in Windows 7.

I have a ZUP power supply module that I am communicating with RS232.

The weird thing is, that if I open HyperTerminal and send the device commands and try to receive result - all works fine.
BUT when I send the same commands in ATEasy and try to read results (and VERIFICATED it using the "monitor" feature), the zap module starts to send endless jibrish until I restart it (unplug it).

All the channel configurations are the same (baud rate etc...).

The set of commands that work in HyperTerminal but not in ATEasy:

```
:ADR01;
:RMT1;
:RMT?;
```

The result in case of HyperTerminal is `:RM1;`

In case of ATEasy the result is just jibrish until device restart.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was entirly something else:

Noise from a motor cable was injected into the ZUP communication cable.

So everytime the motor was activated - the ZUP module com channel went crazy!